# Change my URL from https://www.domain.com to https://domain.com

Tags: redirect, dns

I have migrated my site to Godaddy and Installed WordPress, but it get installed on https://www.domain.com on previous hosting it was simply on https://doamin.com.

Now I am having problem as some pages & resources gives 404 not found error unless I write "www" at the start of the URL.

I have tried to install a clone of my WordPress on https://domain.com but when I visit it still give 404 error unless I write www at start.

I think I haven't setup the DNS record accurately.

Please can someone help me change the URL.

Here is the current website link:

https://www.diamondpaints.com/

I want to move it to:

https://diamondpaints.com/

Comment: That's huge overkill, you should just add a rewrite rule, it's probably available as a checkbox in the hosting panel.

Comment: @tripleee Can you guide me to the right direction please